# MinIO doesn't delete empty folder(path) in Java

Tags: java, minio

My problem is with MinIO 8.3.3 in a Spring Boot application.
I have a bucket called "mybucket".
I can upload several files into a path, let's say "myfolder", so that I have files:
"myfolder/file1.png",
"myfolder/file2.png"

I know how to delete them, and I have success in it.
The problem I am facing is that the empty folder "myfolder" remains, although it is meant to be automatically deleted after the last from it is is removed.

I even tried to remove the folder itself with both

```
RemoveObjectArgs args = RemoveObjectArgs.builder().bucket("mybucket").object("myfolder");
minioClient.removeObject(args);
```

and

```
RemoveObjectArgs args = RemoveObjectArgs.builder().bucket("mybucket").object("myfolder/");
minioClient.removeObject(args);
```

But the empty folder is not removed. Where do I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable MinIO Bucket Versioning? If yes, you should "delete all versions of the object" in order to prevent dangling objects inside the folder.
Also in my experience, it takes some time to automatically delete the folder after the last object is removed (a few minutes to a few days)

Comment: Yes I did. Sometimes it simply removes the emptied folder (I am cleaning up the file versions). And inspecting the folder in MiniO UI, it tells me it is empty, but still present. It's a weird behavior.

Comment: is it possible delete all the files inside the folder without listing and delete each and every file

Answer (score 0):

MinIO does not provide a method to delete folder("path"), But we can use a little trick:

1. Delete file recursive with prefix(called folder or path).
2. Overwrite the prefix by a empty file.
3. Then delete this file.